# Second derivative of implicit equation in "How Not to Land at Lake Tahoe"

Tags: derivatives, implicit-differentiation, implicit-function

I was trying to replicate the math "[How not to land in Lake Tahoe](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/0002989058023.di991772.99p0579p.pdf)" problem by Barshinger (1992) in the American Mathematical Monthly.

Essentially, he models the landing path of a plane with a cubic polynomial.

[image]

The resultant equation is

$y(x)=h({2(x/L)^3+3(x/L)^2})$

The velocity is intuitively the implicit differentiation of the landing path function as stated in the original problem solution:

$\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{6Uh}{L}((x/L)^2+(x/L))$

$U = \frac{dx}{dt}$ assuming that the after the implicit differentiation, the horizontal velocity is constant.

However, I am stuck when he takes the second derivative to get the vertical acceleration of the plane on the landing path. I understand that in kinematics that acceleration is simply the derivative of the velocity. However, I am unsure how he arrived at the below expression for acceleration.

$\frac{d^2y}{dt^2}=\frac{6U^2h}{L^2}(2(x/L)+1)$

I understand the latter part - $(2(x/L)+1)$ which is just following the normal differentiation rules. However, I don't know how to arrive at the $\frac{6U^2h}{L^2}$ term with the $U^2$ and the $L^2$ components. Why are they raised to the power of 2? Is this some kind of chain rule or product rule that I'm missing?

Comment: $U$ and $L$ appear again for the exact same reason as they do in the first derivative.

Comment: @Stuck I understand they need to be there but I'm not quite sure why they are raised to the second power.  Is this an application of the chain rule? How would you differentiate the $\frac{6Uh}{L}$ term?

Comment: All that happened with L is that it was factored out of the brackets. $U$ appears again via the chain rule, and we don’t see a $\mathrm{d}U$ term because you said it is constant

Comment: @djtech You don't. It is constant so it's just along for the ride. You use the chain rule on the terms involving $x$ (i.e. $(x/L)^2$ and $(x/L)$) in the same way as you did for the first derivative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this context, $U$, $h$ and $L$ are all constants and $x$ is a function of $t$: $x(t) = Ut$.

Now with $y'(t) = \frac{6Uh}{L}((x(t)/L)^2 + x(t)/L)$, you take the derivative again and get
$$\begin{align*}
y''(t) & = \frac{6Uh}{L}(2x(t)x'(t)/L^2 + x'(t)/L) \\
& = \frac{6Uh}{L}(2 x(t) U / L^2 + U/L) \\
& = \frac{6U^2h}{L^2}(2 x(t) + 1),
\end{align*}$$
so the only thing that is happening is that the constant factor $U/L$ appearing in both terms inside the parentheses is moved outside of the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

(A little too long for a comment)

It might be easier to see what is being done if common factors are extracted as soon as they appear. Starting with Barshinger's trajectory function, we have

$$ y \ \ = \ \ h·\left[ \ 2 \left(\frac{x}{L} \right)^3 \ + \ 3 \left( \frac{x}{L} \right)^2 \ \right] \ \ = \ \ \frac{h}{L^2}·\left[ \   \left(\frac{2}{L} \right)·x^3 \ + \ 3· x^2 \ \right] \ \ .  $$

So differentiation with respect to time produces
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{dy}{dt} \ \ = \ \ \frac{h}{L^2}·\left[ \   \left(\frac{6}{L} \right)·x^2 \ + \ 6· x \ \right]·\frac{dx}{dt} \ \ = \ \ \frac{6h}{L^2}·\left[ \   \left(\frac{1}{L} \right)·x^2 \ + \ x \ \right]·U $$
(with the Chain Rule producing the velocity factor, taken to be a constant value $ \ U \ \ ) $
$$ = \ \ \frac{6h·U}{L^2}·\left[ \   \left(\frac{1}{L} \right)·x^2 \ + \ x \ \right] \ \ . $$

The second implicit differentiation with respect to time in order to obtain the vertical component of acceleration creates another "chain rule factor" of horizontal velocity, giving us
$$ \Rightarrow \ \ \frac{d^2y}{dt^2} \ \ = \ \ \frac{6h·U}{L^2}·\left[ \   \left(\frac{2}{L} \right)·x \ + \ 1 \ \right]·\frac{dx}{dt} \ \ ,   $$
and so to the stated result.